# Gradle multi module dependencies

Tags: java, android, spring, gradle, spring-boot

I have a Spring Boot multi module Gradle app.

Everything builds and runs locally without issue however the JARs being output by my subprojects do not contain any of the required dependencies and strangely the generated manifest contains only `Manifest-Version: 1.0`.

I've tried almost all different combinations I can think of but have now run out of ideas!

Here's my root build.gradle:

```
buildscript {
    ext {
        springBootVersion = "1.5.3.RELEASE"
    }
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
        maven { url "https://plugins.gradle.org/m2/" }
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-gradle-plugin:${springBootVersion}")
        classpath("io.spring.gradle:dependency-management-plugin:1.0.2.RELEASE")
        classpath("de.thetaphi:forbiddenapis:2.3")
        classpath("com.diffplug.spotless:spotless-plugin-gradle:3.3.2")
    }
}

subprojects {

    apply plugin: "java"
    apply plugin: "idea"
    apply plugin: "com.diffplug.gradle.spotless"
    apply plugin: "de.thetaphi.forbiddenapis"
    apply plugin: "io.spring.dependency-management"
    apply plugin: "org.springframework.boot"

    sourceCompatibility = 1.8
    targetCompatibility = 1.8

    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
        flatDir {
            dirs "libs"
        }
    }

    jar {
        baseName = "app"
        version = "0.0.1-SNAPSHOT"
    }

   spotless {
       java {
           googleJavaFormat()
       }
   }

    idea {
        module {
            inheritOutputDirs = false
            outputDir = file("$buildDir/classes/main/")
        }
    }

    task dev {
        doLast {
            bootRun.systemProperty "spring.profiles.active", "dev"
        }
    }

    bootRepackage {
        enabled = false
    }

    bootRun {
        addResources = true
        systemProperties = System.properties
    }

    forbiddenApis {
        // https://github.com/policeman-tools/forbidden-apis/wiki/GradleUsage
        bundledSignatures = [ "jdk-unsafe", "jdk-deprecated", "jdk-non-portable" ]
        signaturesFiles = files("../forbidden_signatures.txt")
        ignoreFailures = false
    }

    dependencies {
        compile("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter") {
            exclude group: "org.flywaydb", module: "flyway-core"
        }
        compile("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-devtools")

        compile("com.google.guava:guava:21.0")
        compile("org.apache.commons:commons-lang3:3.5")
        compile("org.projectlombok:lombok")

        testCompile("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test")
        testCompile("com.h2database:h2")
    }

    dependencyManagement {
        imports {
            mavenBom "org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-dependencies:${springBootVersion}"
        }
    }

    test {
        testLogging {
            events "failed"
            exceptionFormat "full"
        }
    }
}
```

And the gradle.build for one of my subprojects:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
        maven { url "https://plugins.gradle.org/m2/" }
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath("com.moowork.gradle:gradle-node-plugin:1.1.1")
    }
}

apply plugin: "com.moowork.node"

dependencies {
    compile project(":core")
    compile project(":search")

    // Spring projects
    compile("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-security")
    compile("org.springframework.security:spring-security-web")
    compile("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf")
    compile("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-mail")

    // Thymeleaf
    compile("nz.net.ultraq.thymeleaf:thymeleaf-layout-dialect")
    compile("it.ozimov:spring-boot-thymeleaf-email:0.5.3")

    // Email
    compile("com.sendinblue:sendinblue:2.0")
    compile("com.icegreen:greenmail-spring:1.5.3")

    // DB
    compile("org.postgresql:postgresql:42.0.0")
    compile("org.flywaydb:flyway-core:4.1.2")
}

ext["thymeleaf.version"] = "3.0.5.RELEASE"
ext["thymeleaf-layout-dialect.version"] = "2.2.1"

node {
    version = "7.10.0"
    download = true
}

npmInstall.args = ['--silent']

// make sure node and build dependencies are installed before calling webpack
npm_run_build.dependsOn "npmInstall"

npm_run_build.dependsOn npm_run_lint

// make sure webpack generates assets for the build
processResources.dependsOn npm_run_build
```

Any help or ideas would be hugely appreciated!

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Huzzah!

So it turns out the problem was this:

```
bootRepackage {
    enabled = false
}
```

It was incorrectly being applied to all sub projects. Instead, it was only required for sub projects which weren't boot applications - for example shared modules.

Once I removed this configuration from the `subProjects` task and added it to the shared modules only, the compilation problem was gone.

Hopefully this helps others :)